# Display IST date and time for US Based server in Asp.net Calendar

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net calendar that is used to display events taken from an access database. It works fine, but as the server is US based so according to Indian Standard Time(IST), it changes current day after 12:30 PM (11hrs, 30 min after actual IST time). This gets a little confusing for people using it.

I want a solution so that the calendar changes to today's date at correct time i.e. 12:00 AM IST. Or you may say that the time of the server should be added 11 hrs & 30 min so as to display date according to IST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!

Declared a DateTime variable and with DateTime.UtcNow, added 5 Hrs and 30 Min to the result.
Then this resultant DateTime is used as Today's Date.

```
DateTime todayDate = new DateTime();
todayDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5).AddMinutes(30);
Calendar1.TodaysDate = todayDate;
```